# Node JS showing different results to Javascript console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tested this code below inside the snipped on the Google Chrome Console.

**Input and Output:**

```js
var values = [{"id":"1","Product":"Pen","Qty":"10"},{"id":"2","Product":"Pencil","Qty":"20"}]

for(var key in values) {
  var val = values[key];

  console.log(val);
}
```

**Using NODE JS**

I have installed a module called `body-parser`. To access HTML content from Node JS.

```
// Get HTML values
var {values} = req.body;

// Iterate through the dictionary
for(var key in values) {
  var value = values[key];

  console.log(value);
}
```

This is the actual output on CMD - very different to the Google Chrome Console. I am confused to why it is different.

```
[
{
"
i
d
"
:
"
1
"
,
"
P
r
o
d
u
c
t
"
:
"
P
e
n
"
,
"
Q
t
y
"
:
"
1
0
"
}
,
{
"
i
d
"
:
"
2
"
,
"
P
r
o
d
u
c
t
"
:
"
P
e
n
c
i
l
"
,
"
Q
t
y
"
:
"
2
0
"
}
]
```

How can I get same output as Javascript console? I'd like to access it's `id` and other contents.

It's the same language (Javascript) but different outputs, how does what make sense? Is it because of using Node JS?

**Edit:**

```
Use var {values} = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Comment: It's because in node, you're splitting a string that happens to contain JSON into its characters. Use `var {values} = JSON.parse(req.body);` instead. Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) setup and it should happen automatically.

Comment: req.body is a string not an object, just do JSON.parse(req.body) beforehand

Comment: @ChrisG `TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value` when using `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @ChrisG `[Object: null prototype] {
  id: '1',
  Product: 'Pen',
  Qty '10',
  values: '[{"id":"1","Product":"Pen","Qty":"10"},{"id":"2","Product":"Pencil","Qty":"20"}]'
}`

Comment: `var values = ...` because `var { values } = JSON.parse()` is equivalent to `var values = JSON.parse().values` but your string is a JSON array that doesn't contain a `values` key

Comment: Ok, so it should be `const values = JSON.parse(req.body.values)`. However the actual issue is in the client code that sends the request to your node server, because `req.body` is clearly messed up

Comment: @ki youre absolutely right! I didn't notice that!

Comment: @ChrisG I didn't notice the double variables of `values`

Comment: Yeah, however again, `.values` shouldn't duplicate the Pen, should it? And `req.body` shouldn't contain a JSON string that has to be manually parsed in the first place. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your client side code has a `JSON.stringify` that doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body.values`, from your comments, is a string. Parse it using `JSON.parse` like the following:

```
// Get HTML values
var values = JSON.parse(req.body.values);

// Iterate through the dictionary
for(var key in values) {
  var value = values[key];

  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: What is the console.log output?

Comment: The for loop does not work sorrt - but if I use this `var {values} = JSON.parse(req.body.values);
  console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.values));
// Iterate through the dictionary
for(var key in values) {
  var value = values[key];

}` it shows my correct output

Comment: That's because it's an array. Change it to `JSON.parse(req.body.values)[0]`

Comment: still no output when using the `for loop`

Comment: But when I do this: `  var {values} = JSON.parse(req.body.values);
  console.log(values);` it fives me this output `[Function: values]`

Comment: @handleChange You were supposed to remove the deconstruction on the left, that's why it didn't work for you at first. The array business is the wrong tree entirely.